# How to use return; with functions

Tags: javascript

In some places of my program I use a check that holds the script if the data doesn't match:

```
const a = 1;
//...
//...
if (param1 != 1 && param2 != 3) {
   return; // stop script
}
//...
//...
if (param1 != 1 && param2 != 3) {
   return; // stop script
}
//...
//...
```

So i create function:

```
function checkIfOk(param1, param2)
{
    if (param1 != 1 && param2 != 3) {
       return; // stop script
    }
}
```

But now:

```
const a = 1;
//...
//...
checkIfOk(param1, param2);
//...
//...
checkIfOk(param1, param2);
//...
//...
```

Doesn't pause the function at error.

```
const a = 1;
//...
//...
return checkIfOk(param1, param2);
//...
//...
return checkIfOk(param1, param2);
//...
//...
```

This stops the function in any situation.

I don't want use throw errors because I use it in functions, so program should still running.

Comment: You're not returning a value from checkIfOk, so you can't then return that value later. You'll need to amend your logic to return a boolean, I imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quicker way to implement what you want:

```
function checkIfOk(param1, param2) {
  return (param1 != 1 && param2 != 3);
}

if (checkIfOk(param1, param2))
  return;
```

I guess semantically it should be `checkIfNotOk()`, but eh...

Comment: no round brackets required in the return statement. btw, it should be `ifNotOk`

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm aware, it just makes it a little easier to read. **Update** clearly you didn't read my mentioning of semantics at the end of the answer.

Comment: Yes that's also an option, but I assumed the function is more complex than the current example

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value (e.g. `false` and `true`), and only stop for example when returning `false`

e.g.

```
function checkIfOk(param1, param2)
{
    if (param1 != 1 && param2 != 3) {
       return false; // stop script
    }
    return true; // OK!!
} 

if(!checkIfOk(param1, param2))
   return; //only return if checkIfOk returns false
```

Comment: `return !(param1 != 1 && param2 != 3)`

Comment: Yes that's also an option, but I assumed the function is more complex than the current example

Comment: Use if blocks instead of returns?